# Which file do i have to link for SDL_GetClipboardText etc in SDL2?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, sdl

I have been trying to compile a file from the SDL2 test sources

I am currently linking:

```
-lSDL2
-ldl
-lSDL2main
-lSDL2_test
-pthread
```

yet I am still getting undefined reference errors.

Comment: You should post the errors you get.

Comment: Having the exact same problem as you, OP. Did you find out the solution?

Comment: @gromit190 I can't remember, this was 5 years ago,
(assuming linux) installing libsdl2-dev and then doing `dgkg -L libsdl2-dev` shows the libs installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` then doing `nm libSDL2.a | grep GetClipboardText` shows the proc to exist in libSDL2.a which means -lSDL2 should have been sufficient unless said method has dependency on other libs, also a library might need to be linked twice.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the order in which you list your libraries is important for dependency resolution.
The other thing is that you can use

`sdl2-config --libs`

And it'll tell you all you need to know.

Also, if you are compiling tests from SDL2, why not use the autotools build system provided (configure/make)?

Comment: Actually, the link error turns up when you -lSDL2_test. If you need to link to this (for example, because you're compiling a test), then your answer isn't very helpful.